# Show entity reference content with a field other than the title

Tags: theming, 8, entities

I want to add a field to a custom content type that allows users to select other content from the site to display as a list on the given node.

I can do this by creating an entity reference field to content type. This works, but I can only seem to have it show the link in reference to the Title field of the corresponding node. I want to set a different field as the link. How do I do this?

If I could show the fields in a view, I could select the field to show more easily, however, I have not found a way to have a view show the contents of a field from the current page.

Originally, I had implemented this via a system of taxonomy terms and a view but my users want the ability to go in and manually set the relationships so I have had to fall back to this. If someone has a better suggestion for this problem I would love to hear it.

Comment: you want to show the content field than title to user while selecting? Did you tried [Entity Reference Views Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_reference_views_select) module, if it works?

Comment: Ideally the user would still select based on the title. We just have a custom 'teaser-heading' field for display in lists and menus etc. Actually, really ideally the user would be able to choose for each item which is displayed.

Comment: I found this tutorial helpful: https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/how-alter-entity-autocomplete-results-drupal-8

Answer (score 2):

I've done this before:

You can override the Autocomplete field widget, so instead of title, it will give you back something else! You need to inheritance the existing one and after 2-3 of other inheritance you will be able to reach the autocomplete ajax functionality and rewrite it. It's pretty complex, but not impossible!

Comment: This approach makes me curious, any suggestions where I can read more about doing this? I have worked around the issue for now by creating a view but would prefer to have control over the fields themselves.

Comment: Sure! I will get you the answer when I get back to the office on monday!

Comment: Could you share that with me too?

Comment: I was able to do what I needed. I found this tutorial helpful: https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/how-alter-entity-autocomplete-results-drupal-8

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the module you are looking for: https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form